# HTTP header expires Implementation in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, http, header, expires-header

I am implementing HTTP Header expires implementation in Wordpress - say browser side caching for reducing the number of hits to server as well as decrease the loading time by loading css/images/js files from browser and not the server.

Following is what I have added in .htaccess as of now

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">  
FileETag none
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

With above code, I could see all js files loaded from theme folder have their expiry set to one month, but what about the jQuery file that comes from the js folder? The above entry in .htaccess doesn't target that. Can we cover them too?

QQ- Any way to cache the js/css/images or override their expiry time and let us set own(longer) time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType image/x-icon .ico
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css M604800
ExpiresDefault M604800
</IfModule>
```